# Java - Turn a string of letters into equivalent words

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java and would be grateful for any help anyone can give me

I need to write a program that asks the user for a string of 5 characters, for example asdfg, and converts these into words, such as 'apple spinach dog fish goat'. (These are the letters the user will input)

I have been trying to input these into an array, and change the elements from that but I am not entirely sure how.

This is the code I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;


public class wordsArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the details of your order");
        String myList = scan.nextLine();
    }

        myList[0] = "apple";
        myList[1] = "spinach";
        myList[2] = "dog";
        myList[3] = "fish";
        myList[4] = "goat";

        //Print all the array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
       }


    }
```

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. How would "asdfg" become "fish" ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, a becomes 'apple', s becomes 'spinach', d becomes 'dog', f becomes 'fish' and g becomes 'goat'.

Comment: and if you have second d

Comment: what shall it become

Comment: How should `myList` be a `String` and an Array at the same time? What's that for loop outside your `main`?

Comment: you are in the phase that you should start getting the things out of the main method...

Comment: A second d would also become 'dog'.

Comment: how would you know user will input these asdfg letters ?

Comment: The for loop is supposed to print the list of words, and I did not realise myList was both a string and an array at the same time, it is supposed to take user input into the array and convert these letters into their respective words.

Comment: @mo sean: These are just placement words and letters I am using, the program I want to write will use this to convert other letters into words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code right now.  First, you need to convert the string you receive into an array of chars.  Then, to use your list implementation, you'd have to iterate through both lists to match each input character with the word that starts with that letter.

**A better option is to put the letter-word pairings in a Map** and retrieve them that way.

Finally, you probably don't want to use "System.out.println", because then you get your results on separate lines.  Instead, use "System.out.print."

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the details of your order");
    String myString = scan.nextLine();
    char[] myChars = myString.toCharArray();

    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('a', "apple");
    map.put('s', "spinache");
    map.put('d', "dog");
    map.put('f', "fish");
    map.put('g', "goat");


    //Print all the array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < myChars.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(map.get(myChars[i]) + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its better to put all these things in map.

```
Map<Character,String> dataMap = new HashMap<Character,String>();
dataMap.put('a',"apple");
dataMap.put('s',"spinach");
dataMap.put('d',"dog");
dataMap.put('f',"fish");
dataMap.put('g',"goat");
```

Now print data in required order like below,

```
//Print all the array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(dataMap.get(myList.charAt(i)) + " ");
    }
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, you may accept any of answers

Comment: Thank you for your help! I accepted the other answer as it gave more information for anybody with the same problem as your solutions were the same, but I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. But here is a simple solution to your problem

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the details of your order");
        String myList = scan.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<myList.length();i++){
            switch(myList.charAt(i)){
                case 'a':System.out.println("Apple");
                break;
                case 's':System.out.println("Spinach");
                break;
                case 'd':System.out.println("Dog");
                break;
                case 'f':System.out.println("Fish");
                break;
                case 'g':System.out.println("Goat");
                break;
                default: System.out.println("Nothing..");
                     break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for the ambiguity of my question it is late and I am tired, so I expect I don't make much sense. But thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String inputString = "asdfg"; //your scan.next();

//use array constructor
String [] myList = {"apple", "spinach", "dog", "fish", "goat"};
//start our result string as empty
String result = "";
//for each letter of our input string...
for(char letter: inputString.toCharArray()){
    //...check each of the words in my list to see if they start with that letter
    for(String word: myList){
        if(word.toCharArray()[0] == letter){
            result = result + " " + word;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);  //prints "apple spinach dog fish goat"
```

I think that it might be more appropriate to use a map to solve this.

```
//build a map
String inputString = "asdfg"; //your scan.next();
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("a", "apple");
myMap.put("s", "spinach");
myMap.put("d", "dog");
myMap.put("f", "fish");
myMap.put("g", "goat");
//initilize our result string
String result = "";
//split the string and get our values straight from the map
for(String letter: inputString.split("")){
    result = result + " " + myMap.get(letter);
}
System.out.println(result); //" apple spinach dog fish goat"
```

Then you can also approach this functionally, using reduce.

```
String result = Arrays.stream(inputString.split("")).reduce("", (accumlator, letter) -> accumlator + " " + myMap.get(letter));
System.out.println(result); //" apple spinach dog fish goat"
```